# MySQL - ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'sal' in 'having clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

I need to count the number of employees by department with a salary greater than the average.

My employees table:

```
+------+--------+-----------+------+------------+------+------+--------+
| eno  | ename  | job       | mgr  | hiredate   | sal  | comm | deptno |
+------+--------+-----------+------+------------+------+------+--------+
| 7369 | smith  | clerk     | 7902 | 1980-12-17 |  800 | NULL |     20 |
| 7499 | allen  | salesman  | 7698 | 1981-02-20 | 1600 |  300 |     30 |
| 7521 | ward   | salesman  | 7698 | 1981-02-22 | 1250 |  500 |     30 |
| 7566 | jones  | manager   | 7839 | 1981-04-02 | 2975 | NULL |     20 |
| 7654 | martin | salesman  | 7698 | 1981-10-28 | 1250 | 1400 |     30 |
| 7698 | blake  | manager   | 7839 | 1981-05-01 | 2850 | NULL |     30 |
| 7782 | clark  | manager   | 7839 | 1981-06-09 | 2450 | NULL |     10 |
| 7788 | scott  | analyst   | 7566 | 1982-12-09 | 3000 | NULL |     20 |
| 7839 | king   | president | NULL | 1981-11-17 | 5000 | NULL |     10 |
| 7844 | turner | salesman  | 7698 | 1981-10-08 | 1500 | NULL |     30 |
| 7876 | adams  | clerk     | 7788 | 1983-01-12 | 1100 | NULL |     20 |
| 7900 | james  | clerk     | 7698 | 1981-12-03 |  950 | NULL |     30 |
| 7902 | ford   | analyst   | 7566 | 1981-12-03 | 3000 | NULL |     20 |
| 7934 | miller | clerk     | 7782 | 1982-01-23 | 1300 | NULL |     10 |
+------+--------+-----------+------+------------+------+------+--------+
```

The query I'm trying to do is

```
select deptno, count(*) from emp group by deptno having sal > avg(sal)
```

And that's when I get the error.

I tried this query too:

```
select deptno, count(*), avg(sal) from emp group by deptno
```

Which is basically the same except there is no having clause, and it works as expected.

-

`select deptno, count(*) from emp where sal > avg(sal) group by deptno`

This query throws the following error:

`ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function`

-

`select deptno, count(*) from emp group by deptno where sal > avg(sal)`

And this one is using incorrect syntax:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where sal > avg(sal)' at line 1`

-

Why am I getting this error? Which would be the correct way to execute this query? Thanks in advance.

Insert script:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `emp` (
  `eno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ename` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mgr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hiredate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `sal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comm` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deptno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eno`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10000 ;

INSERT INTO `emp` (`eno`, `ename`, `job`, `mgr`, `hiredate`, `sal`, `comm`, `deptno`) VALUES
(7369, 'smith', 'clerk', 7902, '1980-12-17', 800, NULL, 20),
(7499, 'allen', 'salesman', 7698, '1981-02-20', 1600, 300, 30),
(7521, 'ward', 'salesman', 7698, '1981-02-22', 1250, 500, 30),
(7566, 'jones', 'manager', 7839, '1981-04-02', 2975, NULL, 20),
(7654, 'martin', 'salesman', 7698, '1981-10-28', 1250, 1400, 30),
(7698, 'blake', 'manager', 7839, '1981-05-01', 2850, NULL, 30),
(7782, 'clark', 'manager', 7839, '1981-06-09', 2450, NULL, 10),
(7788, 'scott', 'analyst', 7566, '1982-12-09', 3000, NULL, 20),
(7839, 'king', 'president', NULL, '1981-11-17', 5000, NULL, 10),
(7844, 'turner', 'salesman', 7698, '1981-10-08', 1500, NULL, 30),
(7876, 'adams', 'clerk', 7788, '1983-01-12', 1100, NULL, 20),
(7900, 'james', 'clerk', 7698, '1981-12-03', 950, NULL, 30),
(7902, 'ford', 'analyst', 7566, '1981-12-03', 3000, NULL, 20),
(7934, 'miller', 'clerk', 7782, '1982-01-23', 1300, NULL, 10);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html Have a look

Comment: @Jocelyn I'm using MySQL 5.5.24.

Comment: Can you please post insert scripts for demo data

Comment: @MANISH Done, check the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Join the aggregate with the table

```
select emp.depnto, count(*) from 
(select deptno,  avg(sal) avgsal from employees group by deptno) avg
INNER JOIN employees emp on avg.deptno = avg.depnto
WHERE emp.sal > avg.avgsal
```

**EDIT**

Maybe i thoght to complicated. When the overall-average is meant it is simply

```
select depnto, count(*) from employees
where sal > (select avg(sal) from employees)
group by deptno
```

Comment: Your second solution is the one I was looking for, but I still don't know why it doesn't work using "where sal > avg(sal)" and it does using another query inside it. I would appreciate it if you could clear this up. Thanks for the solution though.

Comment: in the where claus you can't use avg because there is the scope on the single row, on wich later the aggregation will work. In the Having clause the scope is the group, so you only have access to the aggregate functions on the table columns and the grouping columns. Therefor you have to use subselects if you want values not in the scope of row (group in the having clause) think of it: the vlaue of the aggragation determines the rows which to aggregate, how could this work?

Comment: You're right, I never thought of it this way. Thanks a lot for the insight, it's really helpful. Thanks again for the solution too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use HAVING. Try WHERE instead:

```
select deptno, count(*) from emp WHERE sal > avg(sal) group by deptno
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I think the where clause must be before the group by. Your query throws this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where sal > avg(sal)' at line 1`.

Comment: I think it would improve your answer if you could you explain a little about when to use `Having` against `Where` ?

Comment: OH sorry
select deptno, count(*) from emp WHERE sal > avg(sal) group by deptno

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan edit your answer rathert than post corrective comments :-)

Comment: Doesn't work either. `ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function`

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan   an aggregate select filter need having clause  .. is mandatory .. the where clause can't know the result of aggregation function ..

Comment: Sorry :) ,of course.
But it is work for me.
I cannot understand what happened


      select deptno, count(*) from emp group by deptno having sal > avg(sal)

Answer (score 0):

You have comma before from

```
select deptno, count(*) 
from emp 
group by deptno having sal >  (select avg(sal)from emp);
```

Comment: That's a typing error here on Stack Overflow, my bad; the query still doesn't work. Thanks for noticing though.

Comment: I have update the answer -.- with a suggestion .. and why downvote ..the ansewer was correct

Comment: I didn't downvote and I have no idea why anyone would. Sorry about that.

Comment: In SO somtimes someone  ... don't answer .. don't comment but downvote .. let me know if the suggestion is useful

Comment: Same exact error: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'sal' in 'having clause'`

Comment: Same error. The error seems to be on the left part of the '>', not on the right part. It looks like the column 'sal' does not exist, but we know that's not the case...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT deptno as Department , count(eno) as employeeCount from emp
where sal > (select avg(sal) from emp ) group by deptno
```

Comment: `ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`